# Regex numbers from string

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a regex that can find only numbers from given string. What I mean is:

Input: `My number is +12 345 678. I have galaxy s3, its symbol 34abc.`

Output: `345` and `678` (but not `+12`, `3` from word `s3` or `34` from `34abc`)

I tried just numbers (`\d+`) and I combinations with white and words characters. The closest was`^\d$` but that doesn't work as my numbers are part of the bigger string, not whole string themselves. Can you give me a hint?

------- EDIT

Looks like I just don't know how to check a character without actually getting it into result. Like "digit that follow space character (without this space)".

Comment: you can incorporate `"\\s"`, which is any whitespace character

Comment: Which characters do you consider to be delimiters (i.e. the ones which may surround a number)? From your examples it's obvious that spaces and dots are delimiters, whereas the "plus" sign isn't. What about other characters: minus sign, comma, underscore, etc.?

Comment: I don't  know how to use it so that it will much the pattern but won't be a part of an output (digits following whitespace character but without it)

Comment: Alex, at the beginnig it can be only spaces. Then I will think about something more.

Comment: By your definition `678` doesn't fits the match because it's followed by a `.` dot.

Comment: Would also be intersting what language/regex flavor. Something like [`(?<!\S)\d+\b`](https://regex101.com/r/vU9sM8/1) would probably do or if there are floats in the string: [`(?<!\S)\d+\b(?![.,]\d)`](https://regex101.com/r/yV0hD2/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general case, you can make use of [lookbehind and lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?<=^|\s)\d+(?=$|\s)
```

The part which makes it into the captured output is `\d+`. 
Lookbehind and lookahead are not included in the match.

I just included spaces as delimiters in the regex, but you may replace `\s` with any character class, as defined by your requirements. For example, to allow dots as separators (both in front and after the digits), use the following regex:

```
(?<=^|[\s.])\d+(?=$|[\s.])
```

---

The `(?<=^|\s)` should be read as follows:

- `(?<= ... )` defines the *lookbehind* group.
- The expression which must precede the `\d+` is `^|\s`, meaning "either start of the line (`^`) or whitespace".

Similarly, `(?=$|\s)` defines the *lookahead* group (it must follow the captured digits), which is either end of the line (`$`) or whitespace.

---

A note on `\b` mentioned in other answers: it is a nice feature, means "word boundary", but the "word characters" are not customizable. This means that, for example, the "+" character is considered to be a separator and you can't change this if you use `\b`. With lookaround, you can customize the separators to your needs.

Comment: This does *not* match `678`, because it's followed by a period, which is why [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36533775/5221149) has extended the lookahead to allow punctuation symbols.

Comment: @Andreas, true, I mentioned this in the answer. I was following the OP's comment to the question: `at the beginnig it can be only spaces. Then I will think about something more.`

Answer (score 1):

### Safer RegEx

Try this:

```
(?<=\s|^)\d+(?=\s|\b)
```

[image: Demo for Safer RegEx]

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/gU9uK7/1)</kbd>

How it works:

```
(?<=\s|^)          # Start of String OR Whitespace (will not select +)
                   # Positive Lookbehind ensures the data is not included in the match
\d+                # Digit(s)
(?=\s|\b)          # Whitespace OR Word Boundary
                   # Positive Lookahead ensures the data is not included in the match
```

[Lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) do not take up any characters in the match, so they can be used so Capture Groups do not need to be. For example:

```
# Regex /.*barbaz/
barbaz          # Matched Data Result: barbaz
foobarbaz       # Matched Data Result: foobarbaz

# Regex (with Positive Lookahead) /.*bar(?=baz)/
barbaz          # Matched Data Result: bar
foobarbaz       # Matched Data Result: foobar
```

As you can see with the second RegEx, `baz` is never included in the matched data result, however it was required in the string for the RegEx to match. The RegEx above works on the same principle

---

### Not as Safe (Old) RegEx

You can try this RegEx:

```
\b\d+\b
```

`\b` is a Word Boundary. This will, however, select `12` from `+12`.

You can change the RegEx to this to stop `12` from being selected:

```
(?<!\+)\b\d+\b
```

This uses a **Negative Lookbehind** and will fail if there is a `+` before the digits.

<kbd>[**Live Demo on Regex101**](https://regex101.com/r/rV4yF3/1)</kbd>

[image: Demo]

Comment: Just a note: The regex `(?<=\s|^)\d+(?=\s|\b)` will match digits preceded by space and _followed by *any* non-word character,_ e.g. all of these would match: `123+`, `123@`, `123β` (β could be any non-Latin letter), but _not_ `123_`. 
P.S. I'm not the downvoter.

Answer (score 1):

What you seem to want is a sequence of digits (`\d+`) that is preceded by a whitespace (`\s`) or the start of the string (`^`), and followed by a whitespace or punctuation character (`[\s.,:;!?]`) or the end of the string (`$`), but the preceding/following whitespace or punctuation character should not be included in the match, so you need positive lookahead (`(?=xxx)`) and lookbehind (`(?<=xxx)`).

```
(?<=^|\s)\d+(?=[\s.,:;!?]|$)
```

See [regex101 for demo](https://regex101.com/r/aP2bN8/1).

Remember to double the backslashes in a Java literal.